# tkinter can't figure out how to read from a file and put in text entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I've tried many different things, I've scoured the internet, can't find anything so I came here. Hoping someone can help me either find a workaround or a fix.

Code:

```
TextFile = open(os.path.join("F:\Dev\python", "file.txt"), "r")
print(TextFile)


nameFull = "Welcome " + str(TextFile) + "!
```

The text inside the .txt file is taken from a input from another python script.

```
TextFile = open(os.path.join("F:\Dev\python", "file.txt"), "w")
TextFile.write(name)
TextFile.close()
```

Whenever I run it I get this giant mess of stuff as the TextFile variable when printed.

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='F:\\Dev\\python\\file.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Comment: `TextFile` is a file object and need to call `TextFile.read()` to read the content from the file.  Also better to close the file after reading the content.

Comment: ```print(TextFile.read())```, Call the ```read()``` or ```readlines()``` to read the contents of the file

Comment: ah I see, didn't think of that one thanks

Answer (score 0):

`TextFile` in your code is a file object, and you need the `read` method to read the entire content of the file from it:

```
file = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
content = file.read()
print(content)
file.close()
```